# "Access to disposed closure" warning in using statement

Tags: c#, resharper, idisposable, using-statement

I am using a "using statement" to ensure a StreamWriter is being cleaned up properly.

```
using (StreamWriter fout = new StreamWriter(tempFile))
{
    data.ForEach(line => fout?.WriteLine(line));
}
```

I receive the ReSharper warning "Access to disposed closure", which from what I understand is because the variable `fout` may be closed. I understand in certain uses that could happen, but in this case is it possible for `fout` to be already disposed when calling `WriteLine`?

Comment: The exact answer is that it totally depends on what the `ForEach` method does internally with the given delegate. Both I and you know that it won't happen, but the compiler can't be sure, hence the warning.

Comment: As long as you  close the stream after used you shouldnt have any problem coding it without the using statement. But yes if you dont close it, it can causes many levels of pain

Comment: That looks like it's a Resharper warning, not a compiler warning (something you might have mentioned). I believe what it's saying is that the lambda delegate to are passing to `ForEach` has a closure that includes the variable that will be disposed by the Using. If ForEach caches the delegate, it will get access to `fout`after it may have been disposed. Read all the way through https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206669485--Access-to-disposed-closure-in-LINQ. The last post (from a Resharper guy, I think) mostly explains it

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

ReSharper's [`Access to disposed closure`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/AccessToDisposedClosure.html) warning should only happen when LINQ delayed execution captures a reference to a closure that may be disposed before execution occurs.

Whether or not that is the case here is dependent on which `ForEach` method you're calling.  If you're calling `List.ForEach` then you're not composing a delayed execution chain, so `fout` will obviously be valid for every invocation.  ReSharper should certainly know better when it comes to this method.

But there are other `ForEach` methods out there, including custom ones, that ReSharper may not know about or that may in fact be delayed.  If they're well-written then they will block until they complete, but I've seen custom `ForEach` extension methods that don't.  Since ReSharper can't know for certain unless the code tells it with an `InstantHandle` annotation on the action parameter, it warns you.

If you're working with [`List.ForEach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.foreach) here then I'd suggest that you drop it in favour of a good old `foreach` statement.  For other extensions, find out if it blocks or if there's any chance that it will defer execution under any circumstance.  [`Observable.ForEach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/reactive-extensions/hh211815(v%3Dvs.103)) and [`Parallel.ForEach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Threading_Tasks_Parallel_ForEach__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Action___0__) both appear to block execution until the collection is fully processed or the event source closes.  Other code may not do so, and tracking down bugs like that can be a pain after the fact.  Check the source for the method if you can, or reach out to the library developer if you can't get access to the source.

Once you've established that this `ForEach` is definitely going to block and never defers execution then you can go ahead and suppress the warning:

```
// ReSharper disable AccessToDisposedClosure
data.ForEach(line => fout?.WriteLine(line));
// ReSharper restore AccessToDisposedClosure
```